# Мерцание gif в android gif drawable

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Используя гифку с помощью этой библиотеки https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable,получил мерцание самой гифки.У самого автора ясного ответа не получил.

```
<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_lampochka"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

Вот код при котором появляются эти дефекты.

Comment: А в чем вопрос?

Comment: Как исправить дефекты?